# Configure Nginx to serve a node js app from a location within root directory

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I am trying to serve a Node JS app alongside some static sites that are already functioning and only serving static content (/insta-app is one of the apps, there is another nginx file with another server block for the other ones which sit on different subdomains). I am successfuly getting the server.js app when I navigate to the URL /nodejsapp. The problem is that all the static content the app requires does not get served and comes up as a 404 (images, js files and css). I wrote a location block for nodejsapp/dist where the static content exists but this did not fix the problem. The content is being requested by a handlebars template that gets successfully called and is sitting in a views folder in the root. I am running the whole thing on an ubuntu server, and the node app is running through pm2 which is working fine when I request curl localhost:3000. How can I get the static content into the server?

Nginx server block:

```
 server {
        listen 443 ssl default_server;

        root /var/www;
        index index.html index.htm server.js;

        server_name uat.com www.uat.com;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/uat.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/uat.com/privkey.pem;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ /.well-known{
                allow all;
        }

        location /insta-app{
                alias /var/www/insta-app/html;
                allow all;
        }

        location /nodeJsApp{
               proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }

         # attempt to serve the static content of the app
        location /nodeJsApp/dist{ 
                root /var/www/sydney-sevens/dist;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }
}
```

Comment: When you open the app in your browser what is the URL request? What does NGINX report in the error log? My guess is that the URL request isn't hitting the location block you are expecting.

Comment: Hi Alan, the request is https://uat.com/nodejsapp/. Here is the request header:

Comment: `Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:uat.com
Pragma:no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36`

Comment: The Nginx erro log says `26159#0: server name "www.uat.com/sydney-sevens" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:79`

Comment: Post the actual request the 404's, it should be in your browser's console window.

Comment: `GET https://uat.com/nodejsapp/dist/css/style.css 404 (Not Found) (index):6``GET https://uat.com/nodejsapp/dist/js/index.js 404 (Not Found) (index):23``GET https://uat.com/nodejsapp/dist/img/picture.png 404 (Not Found) (index):16`